# Remove "p." from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to remove a string ("p.") that is appearing before each page number in the Table of Contents. 
I have this on the .sty file:

```
%table of contents
\renewcommand\@dotsep{2}

\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
\begingroup
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ABNTpagenumstyle}}
    {\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3.5em}}
    {}
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  \leavevmode \normalsize\ABNTtocchapterfont
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
  \hskip -\leftskip
  #1\nobreak\dotfill \nobreak%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ABNTpagenumstyle}}
     {%
      \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss 
        \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#2}{}}{{\normalfont p.\thinspace#2}}{}}\par
     }
     {%
      \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
     }
  \penalty\@highpenalty
\endgroup
\fi}

\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{0em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{0em}{4.1em}}
```

When I remove "p." from the following line:

```
\ifthenelse{\not\equal{#2}{}}{{\normalfont p.\thinspace#2}}{}}\par
```

I get this:
[image: "p." removed from upper levels]

I was able to remove "p." from upper levels. How can I remove "p." from the lower levels?

These are the packages being used:

```
\documentclass[tocpage=plain,espaco=simples,appendix=Name]{abnt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntcite}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{uff} % the .sty file
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

Comment: you need to do the same with `\@dottedtocline` command.

Comment: Where can we find this `abnt` class?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: See http://mtm.ufsc.br/~krukoski/pub/Latex/

Comment: `abnt` is a really old class -- why not use abntex2?

Comment: @Joseph I am using a model provided by my University. I changed only the strictly needed. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: Sure, if the university has provided a template, they should have provided it officially and ready-to-use. This is a _2004_ unsupported class, which doesn't even follow the _2003_ NBR 6027 rule... which doesn't mean it's not a usable class, of course... considering of course that the own authors recognize that `abnt` rules are obnoxious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following redefinition to your style file:

```
\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ABNTpagenumstyle}}
     {%
      {\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.5em}%
       \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{3.5em}
       \old@dottedtocline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
             {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{\thinspace#5}}}%
     }%
     {\old@dottedtocline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
}
```